# Fortran & Matlab linking -- undefined symbols

Tags: compiler-errors, linker, fortran, mex, gfortran

I have inherited this mex code written in fortran 90 that I can't manage to properly build. All the object files compile nicely, but the linking fails.
Fortunately, I have several leads to go on to figure out the problem.

The only complaint from the linker is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mxgetstring_", referenced from:
      _mexfunction_ in qgstep_mex.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Now `mxGetString`is only called in one place in [`qgstep_mex.f90`](http://read.pudn.com/downloads138/sourcecode/math/594307/EnsembleKalman_filter/models/QG/f90/qgstep_mex.f90__.htm)

```
status = mxGetString(prhs(3), prmfname, STRLEN)
```

So if I change this to

```
status = 0
```

and hardcode `prmfname`, the package builds just fine. But of course I don't want to hardcode it.

I have, however, managed to build another program that uses `mxGetString()`, namely the Matlab-supplied example file [`revord.f`](http://kdeforge2.unl.edu/fedora/SOURCES/matlab/matlab/extern/examples/refbook/revord.F)

Both of these programs are linked by the same command made by mex

```
gcc -O -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/ -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -bundle -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/extern/lib/maci64/fexport.map  -o  "revord.mexmaci64"  revord.o  -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -L/opt/local/lib/gcc47/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12/4.7.3/../../.. -lgfortran -L/opt/local/lib/gcc47/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12/4.7.3 -lgfortranbegin
```

except that `revord.F` is substituted by `qgstep_mex.f90` and similarly for the output name.

There is an include statement in `revord.F`

```
#include "fintrf.h"
```

which is pointed to during the compilation by the flag

```
-I/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/extern/include
```

However, if I try to put this in `qgstep_mex.f90`, the linker just complains with

```
Warning: qgstep_mex.f90:1: Illegal preprocessor directive.
```

So, does anyone know how to get this working?

### Update (in response to M.S.B.'s answer)

Changing the case of the extension to .F90 had no effect, but the `-cpp` flag seems to have done the trick. However, now it gives an error (during compilation, not linking) that I do not quite understand (I'm not very good with Fortran)

```
$ gfortran-mp-4.7 -c -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/extern/include -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/simulink/include -fexceptions -m64 -fbackslash -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -cpp "qgstep_mex.f90"
qgstep_mex.f90:102.11:

  status = mxGetString700(prhs(3), prmfname, STRLEN)
           1
Error: Function 'mxgetstring700' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

The relevant lines from the include file seems to be

```
#if defined(MX_COMPAT_32)
.
.
.
#define mxGetString mxGetString700
```

### Update in response to M.S.B.'s update

Aha. It seems I'm not supposed to include `fintrf.h` after all. There's another file in the project directory, [`mexf90.f90`](http://read.pudn.com/downloads138/sourcecode/math/594307/EnsembleKalman_filter/models/QG/f90/mexf90.f90__.htm), containing

```
module mexf90_mod
  interface
     function mxGetString(p, string, STRLEN)
       integer(8) :: mxGetString
       integer(8) :: p
       character*(*) :: string
       integer(4) :: STRLEN
     end function mxGetString

     function mxGetPr(pm)
       integer(8), pointer :: mxGetPr
       integer(8) :: pm
     end function mxGetPr
.
.
```

The strange thing is that mxGetPr is called just fine in `qgstep_mex.f90`, before mxGetString, but calling mxGetString fails, with the error message as noted originally above. Here's the linking command I use (linebreaks inserted for clarity)

```
gfortran-mp-4.7 -O -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64
-Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/
-mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -bundle -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/extern/lib/maci64/fexport.map
-o "QG_step_f.mexmaci64" utils.o parameters.o helmholtz.o calc.o qgflux.o qgstep.o mexf90.o qgstep_mex.o
-L/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -L/opt/local/lib/gcc47/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12/4.7.3/../../..
-lgfortran -L/opt/local/lib/gcc47/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12/4.7.3 -lgfortranbegin
```

As can be seen, the object files do seem to be in the right order as well.

### Update

The package builds just fine on a linux system. Hence I guess it must be some difference between the compilers. Here's the linking code used on the linux system:

```
gfortran -O  -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/ufs/local/matlab-2012a/extern/lib/glnxa64/fexport.map -Wl,--no-undefined
-o  "QG_step_f.mexa64"  utils.o parameters.o helmholtz.o calc.o qgflux.o qgstep.o mexf90.o qgstep_mex.o
-Wl,-rpath-link,/ufs/local/matlab-2012a/bin/glnxa64 -L/ufs/local/matlab-2012a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the filename qgstep_mex.f90 to qgstep_mex.F90.  That will cause gfortran to run the C preprocessor.  There is also a compiler option to cause that.

EDIT in response to the question update:
The compiler wants the function `mxGetString7001` to be typed.  There are several ways that you can do this.  The ideal approach is to have the source code of the function in a module.  Then when the caller `use`s that module, the return type of the function and the types of its arguments are known to the compiler.  Perhaps this exists and you need to add the source code file to your compile statement ... before the file that uses this function.   If not, you could write an `interface` block providing this information.  Or you could declare the function and use an `external` statement, but this is really a work around, using FORTRAN 77 methods.

Answer (score 0):

The include statement in fortran does not have a #

```
include "fintrf.h"
```

When building, why not use gfortran instead of gcc.  Saves the compiler having to figure out what you are compiling.

Comment: I believe the include statement is for the preprocessor, which is why its syntax is different.